# SQL turn row value to new column postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

I'm still new at SQL and still practicing, I keep stuck on this case.

Table i have:

| id | type | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | food | escargot |
| 1 | beverage | red wine |
| 2 | beverage | white wine |
| 2 | food | cheese burger |
| 3 | beverage | champagne |

what I need for the table is to turn row value that have same id to new column.

desired output:

| id | type_1 | name_1 | type_2 | name_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | food | escargot | beverage | red wine |
| 2 | beverage | white wine | food | cheese burger |
| 3 | beverage | champagne |  |  |

I've tried use `case when`, but I should make the value specific for each column. I appreciate if you can give me some advice to solve the problem I had.

Comment: Include what you've tried; you're asking to pivot your data, about which there are hundreds of questions/answers.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no more than two rows for an ID

Query:

```
    with cte as
     (
      select id,type,name, row_number()over(partition by id order by null)rn from menu
     )
    select id,max(case when rn=1 then type end)type_1,max(case when rn=1 then name end)name_1,
           max(case when rn=2 then type end)type_2,max(case when rn=2 then name end)name_2
    from cte
group by id
```

OUput:

| id | type_1 | name_1 | type_2 | name_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | food | escargot | beverage | red wine |
| 2 | beverage | white wine | food | cheese burger |
| 3 | beverage | champagne | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3mkKeaI4)